# Retrieve requesting node's external id inside INodePasswordFilter a SymmetricDS 3.5.x extension point

Tags: java, spring, authentication, passwords, symmetricds

I have a retail system where the central node is corp-0 and store node is store-1, 
store-2, etc.
I am using SymmetricDS 3.5.13 to do sync between a store node and a corp node. I have to authenticate every store node that tries to connect the corp node, even after successful registration using my business logic. **Using a class implementing INodePasswordFilter, how can I retrieve the connection requesting store's external-id ?**
Any help on the configuration and work flow of SymmetricDS password rendering and saving is appreciated.
The class implementation I tried is as given below.

```
public class AuthenticationClinic implements INodePasswordFilter,IParameterFilter, INodeGroupExtensionPoint{
@Override
public String onNodeSecurityRender(String password) {

    // I have to get the NodeGroupId and ExternalId of the
            // requesting node here
            // String external_id= *Method to retrieve External Id of Requesting Node*
            // if(checking.checknodeauthenticity(external_id)) return password;
            // else return "dummy";

    return "dummy";
}

@Override
public String onNodeSecuritySave(String password) {

    return password;
}

@Override
public String[] getNodeGroupIdsToApplyTo() {
    return new String[] { "store" };
}

@Override
public String filterParameter(String key, String value) {
    return value;
}

 public boolean isAutoRegister() {
        return false;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you Garrett for reviewing. 
Is the above question understandable?

Answer (score 1):

Declare your filter to implement `ISymmetricEngineAware`, declare a field `engine` and a method

```
@Override
public void setSymmetricEngine(ISymmetricEngine engine) {
  this.engine = engine;
}
```

Then use the field `engine` to fetch the sql template:

```
ISqlTemplate sqlTemplate = engine.getSymmetricDialect().
   getPlatform().getSqlTemplate();
```

<strike>Use</strike>

```
ISqlTemplate sqlTemplate = AbstractSymmetricEngine.
  findEngineByName("my.symmetric.ds.engine").
  getSymmetricDialect().getPlatform().getSqlTemplate();
```

to query the database using one of the templates from [NodeService](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/symmetricds/code/tags/symmetric-build-3.5.13/symmetric-core/src/main/java/org/jumpmind/symmetric/service/impl/NodeService.java).

Comment: Thank you for your Answer, I will try it out and give feedback within few days.